# Button click event listener is only called once

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a class with several buttons from which the user can choose a number, but after the click listener fires once, it no longer gets called.  The code pen (https://codepen.io/jasonws/pen/qBZeMMB) is a significantly simplified version which still displays the issue.  Any chance someone could take a look at this and let me know what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

```js
class Utilities {
    selectedSession = "Second";

    constructor () {
        const self = this;

        this.manage();

        $("button").on("click", function(e) {
            self.message("Button click: switching to " + this.value + ".");
            self.selectedSession = this.value;
            self.manage();
        });
    }

    manage() {
        const self = this;
        const sessions = [ "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth" ]
        var code;
        $("#picker").empty();
        this.message("Manage: " + this.selectedSession + " is selected.");
        sessions.forEach(function(entry) {
            code = "<button type='button' value = '" + entry + "'";
            if (entry == self.selectedSession) { code += " style='background-color: gray;'"}
            code += ">" + entry + "</button>";
            $("#picker").append(code);
        });
        $("#content").text($("#picker")[0].outerHTML);
    }

    message(text) {
      if ($("#messages").text() != "") { $("#messages").append("<br>"); }
      $("#messages").append(text);
    }
}

test = new Utilities();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="picker"></div>
    <textarea id="content" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
    <div id="messages"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you recreate the buttons HTML contents on each click which removes all attached event listeners. You can either reattach them after click, or instead of replacing HTML content adjust button state by modifying existing elements.

Here is working version

```
class Utilities {
selectedSession = "Second";

constructor () {
    const self = this;

    this.init();
    this.manage();

    $("button").on("click", function(e) {
        self.message("Button click: switching to " + this.value + ".");
        self.selectedSession = this.value;
        self.manage();
    });
}

manage(){
    this.message("Manage: " + this.selectedSession + " is selected.");
    var buttons = $("button")
    for(var x = 0; x < buttons.length; x++){
      var button = buttons[x]
      if(button.value === this.selectedSession){
        button.style.backgroundColor = "gray"
      } else {
        button.style.backgroundColor = ""
      }
    }
}

init() {
    const self = this;
    const sessions = [ "First", "Second", "Third", "Fourth", "Fifth" ]
    var code;
    $("#picker").empty();
    sessions.forEach(function(entry) {
        var buttonHtml = `<button type='button' value='${entry}' >${entry}</button>`
        $("#picker").append(buttonHtml);
    });
    $("#content").text($("#picker")[0].outerHTML);
}

message(text) {
  if ($("#messages").text() != "") { $("#messages").append("<br>"); }
  $("#messages").append(text);
}
}

test = new Utilities();
```

Comment: Thanks!  I'll need to create the event listener every call to manage() because as opposed to in the code pen, the number of sessions in my app changes, but it makes sense that the button elements would need to be maintained or the event listener would need to be recreated.  Thank you for your answer!

Comment: It was my pleasure. However please keep in mind that attaching event listeners on new elements bears a performance penalty. Better approach would be to create once, and manipulate existing elements.